# Linked-j.jar, getConnections() method return null alway

Tags: linkedin-j

I am using `linkedin-j.jar` to get the get the `LinkedIn Profile` using `getProfileById method` but I am not able to fetch the Connections which comes from `getConnection()` method, it is always `return null`.

Can any one help me to come out this issue, below are the code snippet

```
Set<ProfileField> connectionFields = EnumSet.of(ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME,ProfileField.CONNECTIONS)

Person person = client.methgetProfileById("id",connectionFields);
Connections conn = person.getConnections();
```

conn variable is coming as null.

Also I wanted to know that, why it is coming null.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code :

```
 final LinkedInApiClientFactory factory = LinkedInApiClientFactory
            .newInstance(BFF_CONSUMER_KEY, BFF_CONSUMER_SECRET);
            final LinkedInApiClient client = factory
            .createLinkedInApiClient(accessToken);

  Set<ProfileField> fields = EnumSet.of(ProfileField.ID,
          ProfileField.FIRST_NAME, ProfileField.LAST_NAME,ProfileField.CONNECTIONS);

  Person profile = client.getProfileForCurrentUser(fields);   
  Person person = client.getProfileById(profile.getId(),fields);
  Connections conn = person.getConnections();
```